Can I paste rich edit code into a rich edit document rather than to the display buffer, and how?
I want to be able to insert rich edit format code into the existing rich edit document. What I get when I place such data into the clipboard and then do GetRichEditCtrl.Paste() is that data displayed in the CRichEditView screen rather than into the code, and any subsequent call to EmptyClipboard() causes an assertion error. I know that GetRichEditCtrl can make such formatting insertions but I want to be able to insert formatting code not available through such interface.

Not sure what you mean by "into the code".  The rich edit control displays its contents, and if you get those contents it should have the formatting.

The Paste method is specifically to paste clipboard text into the control view. If you want to place it somewhere else then you will need to capture the clipboard data and write/copy it to the destination you want. But it is not clear from your question where you want to place it.
